# Comparing between two arrays

Tags: sorting

How can I compare between two arrays with sorted contents of integer in binary algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read the doc about how to ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as this question needs a LOT of work to be acceptable.

Comment: Why did you delete the content of your question?

Answer (score 3):

As in every case: it depends.

Assuming that the arrays are ordered or hashed the time complexity is at most O(n+m).

You did not mention any language, so it's pseudo code.

```
function SortedSequenceOverlap(Enumerator1, Enumerator2)
{ while (Enumerator1 is not at the end and Enumerator2 is not at the end)
  { if (Enumerator1.current > Enumerator2.current)
      Enumerator2.fetchNext()
    else if (Enumerator2.current > Enumerator1.current)
      Enumerator1.fetchNext()
    else
      return true
  }
  return false
}
```

If the sort order is descending you need to use a reverse enumerator for this array.

---

However, this is not always the fastest way.

If one of the arrays have significantly different size it could be more efficient to use *binary search* for a few elements of the elements of the shorter array.

This can be  even more improved because when you start with the median element of the small array you need not do a full search for any further element. Any element *before* the median element must be in the range *before* the location where the median element was not found and any element *after* the median element must be in the upper range of the large array. This can be applied recursively until all elements have been located. Once you get a hit, you can abort.

The disadvantage of this method is that it takes more time in worst case, i.e. O(n log m), and it requires random access to the arrays which might impact cache efficiency.

On the other side, multiplying with a *small* number (log m) could be better than adding a *large* number (m). In contrast to the above algorithm typically only a few elements of the large array have to be accessed.

The break even is approximately when log m is less than m/n, where n is the smaller number.

---

You think that's it? - no

In case the random access to the larger array causes a *higher latency*, e.g. because of reduced cache efficiency, it could be even better to do the reverse, i.e. look for the elements of the *large* array in the *small* array, starting with the median of the large array.

*Why should this be faster?* You have to look up much more elements.

Answer:

- No, there are no more lookups. As soon as the boundaries where you expect a range of elements of the large array collapses you can stop searching for these elements since you won't find any hits anymore.
  In fact the number of comparisons is exactly the same.
- The difference is that a *single* element of the large array is compared against different elements of the small array in the first step. This takes only *one* slow access for a bunch of comparisons while the other way around you need to access the same element several times with some other elements accesses in between.
  So there are *less slow accesses* at the expense of more fast ones.

(I implemented search as you type this way about 30 years ago where access to the large index required disk I/O.)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that they are sorted, then you can have a pointer to the beginning of each array, and move on both arrays, and moving one of the pointers up (or down) after each comparison. That would make it O(n). Not sure you could bisect anything as you don't know where the common number would be.

Still better than the brute force O(n2).

Comment: How come complexity is O(n), finding element in sorted array takes O(logN) using binary search you just need to do that twice, am I missing something?

Comment: How do you know which number you are looking for? If you know which one, yes, it's O(log(n)), but you have to try all of the number of one array, so that's O(n).

Comment: Depends on the task but lets say if you are looking for every number in array A if it exists in array B, yes then it will take O(NlogN) time, but you can't beat that I think.

Comment: O(n). Both arrays are already sorted, so you only have at most 2n comparisons (or n+m as explained in the other great answers).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the second array is sorted you can use binary search to look through the second array for elements from the first array.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways. 
a) Binary Search b) Linear Search

For Binary Search - for each element in array A look for element in B with binary search, then in that case the complexity is O(n log n )

For Linear Search - it is O( m + n ) - where m, n are sizes of the arrays. In your case m = n.

Linear search :

1. Have two indices i, j that point to the arrays A, B
2. Compare A[i], B[j]
3. If A[i] < B[j] then increment i, because any match if exists can be found only in later indices in A.
4. If A[i] > B[j] then increment j, because any match if exists can be found only in later indices in B.
5. If A[i] == B[j] you found the answer.

Code:

```
private int findCommonElement(int[] A, int[] B) {

    for ( int i = 0, j = 0; i < A.length && j < B.length;  ) {
      if ( A[i] < B[j] ) {
        i++;
      } else if ( A[i] > B[j] ) {
        j++;
      }
      return A[i];
    }
    return -1; //Assuming all integers are positive.
}
```

Now if you have both descending, just reverse the comparison signs i.e. if `A[i] < B[j]` increment `j` else increment `i`

If you have one descending (B) one ascending (A) then `i` for `A` starts from beginning of array and `j` for `B` starts from end of array and move them accordingly as shown below:

```
for (int i = 0, j = B.length - 1; i < A.length && j >= 0; ) {
   if ( A[i] < B[j] ) {
       i++;
   } else if ( A[i] > B[j] ) {
       j--;
   }
   return A[i];
}
```